# Make ease-in-out faster for fullscreen background image slideshow

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a fullscreen slideshow:
http://codepen.io/jdvs1/pen/ZbpJvJ
There's a really long delay between the first slide and the second slide, about a second of a blank, black screen

I want the transition between images to be relatively quick, <1s, and not include a delayed view of a blank, black screen. How can I do this? I've been playing around with the keyframes for hours.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

  <ul class="slideshow">

    <li>

      <h3>The Seasons</h3>

      <!-- By Keven Law from Los Angeles, USA (Long Hot Summer......) [CC-BY-SA-2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons, http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AFlickr_-_law_keven_-_Long_Hot_Summer.......jpg -->
      <span>Summer</span>

    </li>

    <li>

      <!-- By http://www.ForestWander.com [CC-BY-SA-3.0-us (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/deed.en)], via Wikimedia Commons, http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ARed-fall-tree-lake_-_West_Virginia_-_ForestWander.png -->
      <span>Fall</span>

    </li>

    <li>

      <!-- By Valerii Tkachenko [CC-BY-2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons, http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AWinter_wonderland_Austria_mountain_landscape_(8290712092).jpg -->
      <span>Winter</span>

    </li>

    <li>

      <!-- By Arman7 (Own work) [CC-BY-SA-3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) or GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html)], via Wikimedia Commons, http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ABoroujerd_spring.jpg --> 
      <span>Spring</span>

    </li>

  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 12s linear 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 12s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: imageAnimation 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/summer-slide.jpg);
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/fall-slide.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/winter-slide.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i think i fixed it for you. there were some wonky css:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdgvEq

I fixed this particularly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  1.6% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```